# Divisibility of unitriangular matrices over a field of characteristic 0

Tags: matrices, group-theory, field-theory

Definition: A group $G$ is said to be divisible if for any nonzero integer $n$ and for any $g \in G$ there exists $h \in G$ such that $g = h^n$.

Let $U_n(k)$ be the subgroup of unitriangular $n \times n$ matrices (upper triangular and all diagonal entries are $1$) with entries over a field $k$ with characteristic $0$, where $n \geq2$

Is $U_n(k)$ divisible? (it is true for $n = 2, 3$ if my computations are correct)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know about matrix exponential and matrix logarithm?

Comment: Easier to clear the diagonals one by one